# eureka ios form change background color

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am trying out eureka ios forms and its great, I just can't find how to change the color of the background instead of the light gray it has by default.

[image: Example image]

Comment: Make sure to check closed github issues when using this kind of libraries, chances are someone already had the same problem. In this case: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/834

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer, eureka has a var tableView! that displays the table, to change the color of any part of the table I call this var. so, to set the color of tables background

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1960784346, green: 0.3411764801, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the ViewController that defines the form

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    form
```

add

```
let v:EurekaView = view as EurekaView
v.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

---

Substitute whatever color you need.

Comment: when I type 'eurekaView' I get 'use of undeclared type' error, I have eureka 3.0.0 and put the lines after superviewdidLoad, after the form line the same error. sorry about the confusion total noob in swift.